# How to use ARCamera’s Projection Matrix to de-skew image?

Tags: ios, swift, math, image-processing, arkit

I wanted to de skew the image([snapshot of ARSCNView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/1524031-snapshot)) using the values we get in [projectionMatrix](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2887458-projectionmatrix), or [eulerAngles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2866109-eulerangles) or transform properties of ARCamera. Or is there any other way to de skew image using any values we get from ARKit? My assumption is that projectionMatrix gives us perspective distortion values.
Can we de skew it without selection four points? Any pointers in right direction will be of great help.

Here is one of my try using values of projectionMatrix and eulerAngles:

```
func deskewImage(camera: ARCamera) {
     let rotationZ = CGFloat(camera.eulerAngles.z)

     var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
     transform.m34 = CGFloat(camera.projectionMatrix.columns.2.z)
     transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, rotationZ, 0, 0, 1)

     self.imageView.layer.transform = transform
}
```

I was able to de-skew image using [CIPerspeciveCorrection](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPerspectiveCorrection) using rectangle detection (just like CamScanner apps) but it de-skews only detected rectangle and crops it. I want complete image to be de skewed just like shown in [this example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121822/application-of-the-projection-matrix-removing-perspective-distortion) without selecting four points.

I am looking for the approach using ARKit as values are already threre.

Comment: Sorry if i understand this wrongly. But do you want to take a tilted picture and tilt the picture to make it look straight by using your camera?

Comment: @Vollan yes, thats I wanted

Comment: Hello @AmeetDhas, were you able to find solution on how to use Projection Matrix to get the 2D image coordinates?